# Google Chrome render engine - Unexpected margin, which is removed after hover on image

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome

I found an unexpected problem.

I adds the image inside the DOM. The image has class which contains a
`margin-left: 5px;` attribute. But after rendering in Google Chrome, the `margin` is bigger than it should be, but after I `:hover` on the image, the `margin` is gone. 
Could you explain to me, why it does this? On other browsers it works correctly.

---

### **Images for explanation**

Before hover on image:

[image: Image before hover on image]

After hover on image (the first one):
Here, the `margin` is removed forever. Doesn't extend after hover-off. <sub>Notice the small change between the *pig* and the *spider* avatar.</sub>
[image]

Actually, it's annoying:

```
   <img src="<link>" class="avatar">
   <img src="<link>" class="avatar">
   <img src="<link>" class="avatar">
   <img src="<link>" class="avatar">
```

CSS:

```
.avatar{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[Website with problem on Google Chrome (Sometimes there is not players, so you won't see any avatars, sorry for that.](http://zio.ooo/status)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: code doesn't matter at all. There is nothing more than <img> HTML Tag and margin-right of whom i said above

Comment: Ok, Best of Luck.

Comment: Here you go, code in post. The same od page.

Comment: That can't be the only CSS on your entire page.

Comment: Maybe, i should give you link to site?
[Website with problem on GoogleChrome](http://zio.ooo/status).
Sorry for ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.mc-avatar {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

It will fix your bug.

Comment: That works, but why this bug doesn't appear on other browsers? Google Chrome render this in another way? IIt shouldn't add extra "invisible" margin, i guess

Comment: @Savander Difference between browsers rendering.

Comment: Thank you :) It should be fixed, anyway

Comment: @Savander This article will explains why and how to fix https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @Savander if it works for you, mark my answer as solution please

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't explain why the margin gone after `:hover` on it. In article the space is static, in my example it is dynamic change (`:hover`, don't change margin attribute)